# Problems while adding a number to width attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, setattribute, getattribute

My code should keep making my image wider for 1px every 200ms after a button is clicked, but i feel like it's adding 20-30 instead.

Here's my code
`<img id="testimage" src="wall.png" width="50" height="25"/>`

```
setInterval( function() {var im = document.getElementById("testimage");
    var newWidth = (im.getAttribute("width") ? im.getAttribute("width") : 0) + 1; //here
    im.setAttribute("width", newWidth); console.log(im.getAttribute)}, 200)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the width from a string to a number to perform addition rather than string concatenation. This can be done with the unary plus operator.

```js
var newWidth = (im.getAttribute("width") ? +im.getAttribute("width") : 0) + 1;
```

Alternatively, directly update the `width` property, which is a number.

```js
let im = document.getElementById("testimage");
setInterval(function() {
    ++im.width;
}, 200);
```

```html
<img id="testimage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" width="50" height="50"/>
```